# Mysql View Dump via Bash

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I don't know, if this is correct way of doing this, but here is the scenario. We have multiple servers in multiple locations and each one has a mysql db on it. Each db structure is exactly the same. The goal is to get one or two tables from each database onto one single location.

I don't want to run a bunch of crons on a bunch of different servers. I want to run all the actions on one server namely the server where the consolidated database is living on.

So to dump a table via bash is easy using ssh and mysqldump. The Challenge here is that the data I need does not live in a table but rather in a View. So getting the data requires to do a mysql -e instead of a mysqldump.

But this method dumps the data into a file as data and not as a importable .sql file.

Any guidance and ideas on the above will be fantastic.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Ok so the goal is to run the above command remotely from the consolidation server and getting the file locally, The proccess can then import the data from the view into a normal table with the same structure as the view.

Comment: To clarify: do you hope to export the contents of the view from one server and import it to another as a table? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the data in the view by using SELECT * INTO OUTFILE. e.g.

```
## Exporting data
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/my_out.text' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM m_view;

## Creating migration table
CREATE TABLE m_m_test LIKE migrate_table;

## Loading data from file
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/my_out.text' INTO TABLE m_m_test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Source: https://www.pythian.com/blog/can-just-dump-data-view-using-mysqldump/